# Do we lose out on Spring boot's capabilities/functionality if we package a spring boot application as a WAR instead of a JAR with embedded tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, deployment

I have always deployed spring boot applications packaged as a JAR with an embedded tomcat container. But recently, I had someone ask me if it's ok to deploy a spring-boot application as a WAR. Considering that we can package a tomcat on the VM before deploying the application, the application can be horizontally scaled with VMs. I am guessing the only disadvantage being managing tomcat externally or through scripts. Are there any other limitations?

Comment: You cannot control the tomcat instance from Spring Boot so basically all your `server.*` properties become useless. Also horizontal scaling can be equally done with a Spring Boot application you don't require an external server for that, unless you want a cluster (which is highly overrated imho) and shared state.

Comment: Thank you for the response Deinum. I understand that spring boot application can be scaled as long as the application is designed to be stateless and we can create multiple instances of VMs containing the application regardless of whether it has embedded Tomcat or a standalone installation. Apart from the overhead of tomcat related configuration is there any downside?

Comment: No you don't (and as mentioned imho using a cluster is highly overrated). You can use something like Spring Session to have multiple Spring Boot application share state. Is there more yes you loose part of the auto configuration as Spring Boot isn't in control of the container, basically anything to do with the container you loose. Next to that you have additional deployment overhead, need to check versions and you probably run into some nice class loading issues again.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @M.Deinum